# {ODOO :: Payroll] get total of worked days into another field inside the payslip

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In Odoo 14 community, using hr_payroll_community module, I'm looking to save the total value of 'number_of_days' in worked days tree in another field to allow me use it in another place, and the below screenshot describe the needs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixIg2.jpg)

please advice.... big thanks

Comment: Hint: "enter image description here" is an invitation to enter an image description right where this text is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the image, i need when someone insert any worked_days line in the list to be computed to the custom field i create it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual field names. But you should need a computed field for the total and then calculate the total to it.

```py
total_days = fields.Float(name="Total Days", compute='_compute_total', store=True)

@api.depends('line_ids.days')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.total_days = sum(record.line_ids.mapped('days'))
```